# bash cgi remote ssh

Tags: bash, cgi

I have been searching on Google for this, but not many people seem to write bash cgi...

So I have a little cgi bash script that runs on browser and takes user input, and it should remote ssh to the remote server and get its uptime and store it in a temporary file.

The ssh key exchange has been done, and I can ssh onto the box without password. 
I know the variable is passing down the script, because it does echo back what the user has typed in.
And I know it tries to do something with ssh to the remote host, because the page loads for some times when I click submit.

However, when I look at the temporary file, nothing is there, so somehow ssh is failing but without leaving any error.

Anyone had experience with remote ssh via CGI bash?

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'

echo "<form method=GET action=\"${SCRIPT}\">"\
    '<table nowrap>'\
      '<tr><td>Input</TD><TD><input type="text" name="name" size=12></td>   </tr>'\
                '</table>'

echo '<br><input type="submit" value="Process Form">'\
   '<input type="reset" value="Reset"></form>'

NAME=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*name=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`

echo "NAME: " $NAME
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 -q $NAME uptime > /var/tmp/uptime
cat /var/tmp/uptime
```

Comment: Don't you need a blank line between the content type and actual content?

Comment: oh i had that, i just removed that line to make save space on the post :)

Answer (score 0):

For your ssh command you are using `-q` and `-o ConnectTimeout`, so if connection times out no error message is printed.

If you want debug that ssh command do the following

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 $NAME uptime > /var/tmp/uptime 2>&1
```

That way if ssh fails you will have the error message in `/var/tmp/uptime`